# Custom Event Calendar

Tags: php, events, calendar

Anyone know a good source for building a custom event calendar?

Comment: Maybe a bit more informations on what you really want (and what you have already found ? ) might allow people to help you a bit more... Can you give us more details ?

Comment: I need to build a simple calendar where events can easily be added and viewed.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to start from looking to [other people work](http://www.phpclasses.org/). This are existing classes for calendar applications. You may download them, study, extrapolate or reinvent the wheel if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

use [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) for user interface part

Answer (score 1):

If you want something very simple, you could 'share' your Google calendar and export it onto your website.